# How to validate consumable purchase across multiple devices on an

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

So I've implemented IAP in Android using Unity but one thing remains is how to validate a user across multiple devices.

For instance, user purchases a **consumable** on one phone and then logs in on another phone...

How can I validate the user has made a purchase on the other phone? The purchase is tied to the google account and not the phone. So is there a way to get info about the google account that is logged in currently? Then I could save the receipt behind the scenes and verify when the user logs in on the other phone against a server. But without some unique identifier across phones I would have to force the user to create an account which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently developing an iOS/Android game. The approach I took to this issue was utilizing the [Cloud Save](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) feature offered by Google/Apple. When saving/loading data, there is the chance that there is a conflict with the local vs. cloud data. When there is a conflict, it is here where you will be able to merge data between the local and remote data.

There is a decision at least for Google to choose between the callback resolution of automatically resolving the conflict using one of their default conflict resolutions (longest playtime, newest data, etc.) or manually resolving the conflict. You will want to manually resolve the conflict so you can merge the data together from both saves.

What is important is how you now save this data to the cloud and how you serialize purchases. I will show how I am handling this, but you can approach it in a different way.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class IndividualPurchaseDataSave
{
    public IndividualPurchaseDataSave(string id, bool used)
    {
        purchaseID = id;
        isApplied = used;
    }

    public string purchaseID = "";
    public bool isApplied = false;
}

/// <summary>
/// All purchase data
/// </summary>
[System.Serializable]
public class PurchaseDataSave
{
    public List<IndividualPurchaseDataSave> PurchaseData = new List<IndividualPurchaseDataSave>();
}
```

I have two structures, the first being an individual purchase where the second structure holds a list of all purchases that can be serialized in JSON to push to the cloud.

When the user buys a new in-app purchase, after receiving the Google callback confirmation, I call this function with the purchaseID.

```
/// <summary>
/// Purchases an item and adds it to the dictionary for later usage
/// </summary>
/// <param name="purchaseID"></param>
public void PurchaseItem(string purchaseID)
{
    // adding a delimeter of | to split it later in case we need to handle merging data
    PlayerInAppPurchaseHistory.Add(purchaseID + "|" + System.DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(), true);
}
```

The dictionary structure looks as follows:

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> PlayerInAppPurchaseHistory = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

I am adding the `purchaseID` along with the time purchased in milliseconds as that should be unique enough to never occur again. Wrapping it in a delimiter allows me to still split the string if I need the `purchaseID` for other processing.

When merging the data together, you receive a byte[] from Google and need to convert this data back to something of use. Once you are able to receive the remote data purchase data, you can merge them using a HashSet.

```
// merge the remote INTO the local
HashSet<string> purchaseData = new HashSet<string>();

// add our existing purchases to a hashset
foreach (IndividualPurchaseDataSave data in localPurchaseData.PurchaseData)
{
    purchaseData.Add(data.purchaseID);
}

// now iterate over our remote purchases and if anything is missing, add it to our temp data
foreach (IndividualPurchaseDataSave data in remotePurchaseDate.PurchaseData)
{
    // purchase does not exist, so add it and set it as not applied (false)
    if (!purchaseData.Contains(data.purchaseID))
    {
        localPurchaseData.PurchaseData.Add(new IndividualPurchaseDataSave(data.purchaseID, false));
    }
}
```

After merging the data, you can cache which values are added, but I am reloading the scene as my merge conflict resolution is a bit more complex, so I am adding the new purchases in the Load

```
foreach(IndividualPurchaseDataSave purchaseData in data.PurchaseData)
{
    // if the data is not processed, then process it now - split it over the time
    if (!purchaseData.isApplied)
        ProcessPurchaseItem(purchaseData.purchaseID.Split('|')[0], false);

    // add it to our dictionary
    PlayerInAppPurchaseHistory.Add(purchaseData.purchaseID, true);
}
```

Effectively storing the data in some identifiable way that can be merged at a later time is how you will want to approach this issue. Using cloud saving has no additional cost to me, so that is why I decided to utilize the cloud for this issue. This code is not functional as is, it should be used as a guide.